# How does this code that uses a callback in `XMLHttpRequest` work?

Tags: javascript, callback, xmlhttprequest

This is a very simple callback function but I still can’t wrap my mind around it. Can someone try to explain it to me?

```js
const getToDos = (one) => {
  const req = new XMLHttpRequest();
  req.addEventListener(`readystatechange`, () => {
    if (req.readyState === 4 && req.status === 200) {
      one(undefined, req.responseText);
    }
    else if (req.readyState === 4) {
      one(`couldnt fetch data`, undefined);
    }
  });
  req.open(`GET`, `https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/`);
  req.send();
};

getToDos((err, data) => {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
  else {
    console.log(data);
  }
});
```

Also, can someone tell me what the difference is between `XMLHttpRequest` and the `GET` method? Are `XMLHttpRequest`s used in the front end and `GET` methods used in the back end?

Comment: What do you mean with "get method"?

Comment: In any case, this example uses many antiquated functions and concepts, and it's not something you should look at to learn JavaScript in 2022.

Comment: XMLHttpRequest is a class and get() is a method. What do you mean by **difference**?

Comment: what would this code look like in the modern javascipt @AKX

Comment: when do i use xmlhttprequest and when to use .get? im sorry im just getting my feet wet and i learned about these 2 tonight so its a bit confusing

Comment: Why do you have this tagged `node.js` and `backend`? This is only front-end JavaScript.

Comment: @mark JeanJacquesGourdin's answer has a modern fetch version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
//Defining getToDos function, it takes one argument, which is another function
const getToDos = (one) => {
  //Create a request
  const req = new XMLHttpRequest();
  //Add an event listener on the status of the request and gives code to execute when it happens
  req.addEventListener(`readystatechange`, () => {
    //if request is completed (4) and its status is good (200)
    if (req.readyState === 4 && req.status === 200) {
      //Call the callback function give undefined as error and req.responseText as data
      one(undefined, req.responseText);
    //if request is completed (4) and its status is good (!= 200)
    } else if (req.readyState === 4) {
      //Call the callback function give `couldnt fetch data` as error and undefined as data
      one(`couldnt fetch data`, undefined);
    }
  });
  //prepare request and give endpoint
  req.open(`GET`, `https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/`);
  //send request
  req.send();
};

//execute getToDos function and give a function as parameter
getToDos((err, data) => {
  //if err is not undefined
  if (err) {
    //log error
    console.log(err);
  } else {
    //log data
    console.log(data);
  }
});
```

This kind of code is old. Instead you should :

```
let data = await fetch(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/`, {
  method: 'GET',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    },
  })
if(data.status == 200){
  let parsed = await data.json()
  console.log(parsed)
} else {
  console.log(data)
}
```

–––––
Edit: Added example for the OP

```
const aFunction = (callback) => {
  const aRandomBoolean = Math.random() < 0.5
  if(aRandomBoolean){
    console.log('Boolean is true !')
    callback('first parameter', 'second parameter')
  } else {
    console.log('Boolean is false !')
    callback('parameter 1', 'parameter 2')
  }
}

aFunction((paramA, paramB)=>{
  console.log(paramA, paramB)
})
```

Comment: so i think the course i was watching was trying to use the code i showed as an introduction to the new form. is it okay if i dont fully understand the `antiquated ` code? and just go to the new and updated version of the code that uses await/fetch etc?

Comment: @mark It depends on your opinion on the subject. Personally I think the antiquated version is useful to understand because if you do, you understand both callback and eventlistener, two important features of vanilla javascript.

Comment: oh no i understand the whole eventlistener part and the callback i sometimes use it in my simple code but the  one thing that confused me is that the function he called had 2 parameters  which i never used before thanks for helping me!

Comment: @mark Edited answer with a simple example. Hope it makes it easier to understand the concept. Good luck have fun learning JS =)